# Adding a delay to an Observable "prevents" subscribing in combination with withLatestFrom

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Currently trying to get my head around this:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {delay, first, takeUntil, tap, withLatestFrom} from "rxjs/operators";

const obs1 = new Observable(s => s.next(1)).pipe(delay(1000));
const obs2 = new Observable(s => s.next(2));

obs2
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(obs1),
    tap(() => console.log('tap'))
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log('subscribe'));
```

"subscribe" (and hence "tap") is never logged. But why?

If I remove the `delay` from the first Observable everything works. If I change to `combineLatest([obs1, obs2])` everything works fine.

This is the reproduction of a bug where 2 HTTP requests are sent. If the request within `withLatestFrom` took too long the `subscribe` did never happen. With `combineLatest` everything works as expected (which means the `subscribe` happens *after* both requests are done).

If `combineLatest` fixes my bug I'm fine with that - but I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says:

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom

> All input Observables must emit at least one value before the output Observable will emit a value.

That is because `withLatestFrom()` is a *non-blocking* operator.

`obs2` emits the *first* value, and then `withLatestFrom()` will emit with the latest value from `obs1`, but there is no *latest* value so *nothing* is emitted.

If `obs2` emitted a second value later after `obs1` then a value would be emitted.

> If combineLatest fixes my bug I'm fine with that - but I'd like to understand why.

`combineLatest()` works differently, because it emits **after** all observables emit a value.

Comment: I had a similar problem and combineLatest() fixed it, thanks! But there's something I still don't understand. In my case, the problem Observable takes some time to emit depending on the size of the database table is accesses. With an empty table, the query takes ~50ms and withLatestFrom() works. With a 2-million-record table, it takes ~330ms and withLatestFrom fails. From your description, I would expect it to either fail every time or succeed every time.